# combain two arrays in php array_combine not working?

Tags: php, arrays

**First string:**

`$a = '_edit_last,_edit_lock,wpvp_fp_code,video_category';`

**second string:**

$b = '1,1464965316:1,{"src":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/PHP-Tutorial-1-Introduction-PHP-For-Beginners.mp4","splash":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/default_image.jpg","width":"640","height":"360"},free 200';

Convert String into combined array.

I need out put for:

```
array("_edit_last"=>" 1", "_edit_lock"=>"1464965316:1", "wpvp_fp_code"=>"{"src":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/PHP-Tutorial-1-Introduction-PHP-For-Beginners.mp4","splash":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/default_image.jpg","width":"640","height":"360"}","video_category"=>"free 200");
```

Comment: Can u please provide your both the array in proper format

Comment: `array_combine` requires arrays, but those are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array merges recursive function to merge two arrays

For example

```
 $ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
 $ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
 $result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
 print_r($result);
```

Array Combine Function:

```
 $a = array('_edit_last', '_edit_lock', 'wpvp_fp_code', 'video_category');
 $b = array('1', '1464965316:1', '"{src":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/PHP-Tutorial-1-Introduction-PHP-For-Beginners.mp4","splash":"http://localhost/wbg/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/default_image.jpg","width":"640","height":"360"}','free 200');
 $c = array_combine($a, $b);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($c);
```

[WATCH DEMO](https://eval.in/583154)

Convert sting into array

```
$str = '_edit_last,_edit_lock,wpvp_fp_code,video_category';
print_r (explode(", ",$str));
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/583166)

I have used the double space instead of a comma(,) in string2. Because comma(,) is not a unique function

[DEMO - 3](https://eval.in/583167)

Comment: Please view the alter solution

Comment: sir its work fine but how to convert array of first and second value.

Comment: i getting string value first and second value how to convert array please help...

Comment: Can you elaborate it.

Comment: both value not a array its is string how to convert and combine.

Comment: Modify your question based on the output you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113796/discussion-between-karthi-m-and-balan-k).

Comment: question as been modify check it find solution.

Comment: Please Come into the chat room. Did modified question is correct